# Reactive/Dynamic Markers using Flutter

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter, openstreetmap

I have tried a few different Map based packages in Flutter, however they all seem very basic and don't seem to meet my requirements.

I have had the most luck with the following package.

```
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_map
```

> But I would like to be able to do either of the following
>
> 1. Move a marker point without having the reload the map
> 2. Draw/extend a polyline based on streamed LatLNg objects.

The first should be pretty simple, but all attempts have just ended up refreshing the map, which isn't what I want.

**Question:**

> How can I use dynamically move a marker or draw a poly line in flutter
>   using either google maps or OSM (Open Street Maps)?